# BZR: how to move a folder to a sub folder?

Tags: bazaar

I want to restructure my folder hierarchy in a bzr branch. As part of that I want to move my lib folder down to a new sub folder (lib/x86), that is, all subfolders of lib should then be located under lib/x86. A simple `bzr mv lib lib/x86` doesn't work, neither does moving the lib folder to a new name and then trying to move that to the subfolder.

What's the command to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a wildcard. Assuming you have renamed your lib folder to lib-old you can then move its content like so:

```
bzr mv lib-old/* lib/x86
```

The lib-old folder still exists after that, but that is a simple remove op. I had previously added the new path to bzr, so that might be necessary too.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in 3 steps:

```
bzr mv lib lib-tmp
bzr mkdir lib
bzr mv lib-tmp lib/x86
```

I guess you missed the 2nd step. Btw, `bzr mkdir lib` is equivalent to:

```
mkdir lib
bzr add lib
```